# The inverse of $1+x$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle}$ and elegant methods of this computation

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

I would like to find the inverse of $1+x$ in $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\langle x^2+x+1 \rangle}$ . I argued that the remainder of the division of any polynomial by ${x^2+x+1 }$ is of the form $ax+b$ and after doing the long division and comparing like terms, I concluded that the inverse of $1+x$ is $-x$ in this field.

Now my question is if there are more elegant ways to go about this that preferably avoids long divisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that in this field we have $x^2 + x + 1 = 0 \implies 1 = -x^2 - x = -x(x+1)$.

Thus $-x$ is the multiplicative inverse of $x+1$.